# How to make code that do not use loop system exit

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

Suppose the user inputs any number from 1 to 3, the following prompt should be displayed,  asking the user to choose a meal size.

The following prompt asking if the user wants to include an add-on should display if the user

chooses any meal size.

Loop controls such as break, continue, and pass are NOT ALLOWED. Anything similar to these

(system.exit) are also not allowed

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is python

```
def choose_meal():
    meal_size = input("Choose a meal size (1-3): ")

    # Validate user input
    if meal_size.isdigit() and 1 <= int(meal_size) <= 3:
        print("You chose meal size", meal_size)
        include_addon = input("Do you want to include an add-on? (yes/no): ").lower()

        # Validate user input
        if include_addon == "yes":
            print("Add-on included!")
        elif include_addon == "no":
            print("No add-on included.")
        else:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter 'yes' or 'no'.")
            # Recursive call to restart the process
            choose_meal()
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 3.")
        # Recursive call to restart the process
        choose_meal()

# Start the process
choose_meal()
```